# Document Protection with OpenXML SDK 2

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2007

I am programmatically creating a DOCX file using OpenXML SDK v2.  One of the requirements of the document is it be protected to avoid editing.

This is accomplished using the DocumentProtection object like:

```
new DocumentProtection
{
    Edit = DocumentProtectionValues.ReadOnly,
    Enforcement = BooleanValues.One,
    CryptographicProviderType = CryptProviderValues.RsaFull,
    CryptographicAlgorithmClass = CryptAlgorithmClassValues.Hash,
    CryptographicAlgorithmType = CryptAlgorithmValues.TypeAny,
    CryptographicAlgorithmSid = 4,
    CryptographicSpinCount = 50000,
    Hash = hash,
    Salt = salt
}
```

This works beautifully when the document is opened in Word 2007, but when opened in Word 2003 with the compatibility pack the protection can be removed without entering a password.

Reading online this appears 'by design' or at least expected.

Does anyone have any clever ideas on keeping the password protection in-tact when viewed within Word 2003?

Comment: If this is supposed to be read-only why not serve it as read-only--deliver the documents in a form that can't be edited, such as images in an XPS document?

Comment: Document protection in Word is more a usability feature to avoid unwanted editing than a security feature. The document is not stored encrypted and the protection can easily be removed or circumvented. If you don't want your document to be modified you should apply a digital signature and save it with encryption.

Comment: Unfortunately my requirements are:
- Word document
- Read-only / not editable
- Generated on server (ie no Word Interop, etc.)

Comment: Did you find any solution that fit your requirement (without using  Word automation)?

Comment: I know this is a very old post but can you post an example of how to use the DocumentProtection class